# No module named ouathlib.common

Tags: python, twitter

I downloaded the and installed the twitter wrapper for python from:

```
https://python-twitter.googlecode.com/files/python-twitter-1.1.tar.gz
```

This is all i have in my code now:

```
import simplejson
import httplib2
import twitter
```

This is the error i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\tweets.py", line 3, in <module>
    import twitter
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\twitter.py", line 38, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib-0.4.0-py2.7.egg\requests_oauthlib\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .oauth1_auth import OAuth1
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib-0.4.0-py2.7.egg\requests_oauthlib\oauth1_auth.py", line 3, in <module>
    from oauthlib.common import extract_params
ImportError: No module named oauthlib.common
```

Which module can i install to stop this error?

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/idan/oauthlib

Try to install oauthlib to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

> https://github.com/idan/oauthlib 
>   Try to install oauthlib to fix the
>   error. answered Oct 11 at 12:32 by xiaowl

The above worked for me.  I was installing python-twitter and its dependencies in a web2py application /modules subdirectory and was getting a similar error. I installed oauthlib from the above link and all is happy.

Thanks, Xiaowl.